# Changing Twitter bootstraps table color for a single column?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I just saw this dating site on builtwithbootstrap and have a question about table formatting. The site has a [plenty of fish](http://accentudate.com/free-feature-comparison.php) comparison table and I would like to do a similar format but have a question about changing the color of a specific column. In this example how would I change the font color of the feature column?  I only want the changes to be applied to this table.

I know I can set the font color for each  tag but I'm assuming there must be a better solution.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always assign a div ID to your table and add the specific td style for that specific ID.

```
<table id="customTable">
    ....
</table>

#customTable.td {color: #ff0000;}
```